# Vowpal Wabbit - how it does hashing

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Can anyone explain how the hashing trick is conducted in VW? Specifically, the description below, from the gist:

> the default is hashing / projecting feature names to the machine
>   architecture unsigned word using a variant of the murmurhash v3
>   (32-bit only) algorithm which then is ANDed with (2^k)-1 (ie it is
>   projected down to the first k lower order bits with the rest 0'd out).

Mentions the result of the hash being 'ANDed' with (2^k)-1. What does this mean? I understand if a hash is mod some number D `(hash('my string')%D)`, it results in a new number that can only take on D values. Is this the same as AND'ed? If so, how exactly does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2^k)-1 in binary is "k ones", e.g. (2^6)-1 = 111111(in binary). When you apply [logical AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) on the original hash number and (2^k)-1, you effectively take only the k lower-order bits of the hash. It is the same operation as mod 2^k.